# What would cause graphic glitches like this? (pics attached)

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, graphics, gpu

I have a 2015 15" MBP fully maxed out - GPU, i7, 1TB, running fresh High Sierra install.

I've been having a ton of problems with it throttling (Intel SpeedStep kicking in) even under less than heavy usage. Recently the screen started freaking out, and I managed to capture video of it on my phone (imagine the image you're seeing with the various distorted parts flashing in and out).

The machine is covered by AppleCare. Took it the Apple Store, where it had problems booting some of their diagnostics, they sent it to a service center (along with my video caps). A week later they sent it back saying they couldn't reproduce the problem, sorry.

I'm fairly convinced this is a hardware/GPU issue - anyone ever seen this kind of distortion before?

I'd like to gather some more data points from others before going back to Apple.

[image: graphic glitches]

Comment: It looks like a GPU issue.  What you need to do at this point is create *documentation* in the form of video of when this occurs.  You have AppleCare and you are covered but it looks like you're getting the run-around.  Having documentation will help the Techs validate what you're saying and will help you if you have to escalate the issue because they continue to say "not reproducible"

Comment: @Allan thanks I have several videos (that’s a screen cap from one). I played the videos for the tech in the Apple Store and emailed them to the service center when requested. My biggest challenge is that I am out of the US most of the time in places where there is no authorized Apple service center - I already had to alter travel plans when they had it for a week last month. Not sure what to do next.

Comment: The part that's jumping out to me is that in the Apple Store, it had problems booting *their* diagnostics - that's an issue in and of itself.  Next time you go into an Apple Store, document the conversation and you showing them the video.  You say it's covered under AC; but is it still within the first year?  If you paid by credit card, you may have some protections built in  (AMEX covers it for a year, I think CapitalOne has more protections on top of that).  Check to see if/for what you're covered.

Comment: Most importantly, keep documenting so Apple can't say you brought them the issue after the fact.

Comment: AppleCare expires Dec 2019 (it is a 2015 machine that I got basically at the every end of its sales life for the GPU version). What I'm hoping is that someone else has had a similar issue and can clarify what the eventual cause and resolution was. I won't be in the US again till Jan/Feb.